# Forcing the default Android soft-keyboard to show

Tags: android

I have an activity (forced into protrait mode) that is required to show the default soft-keyboard. So I thought I'd set focus to the edittext when the activity is launched... so far so good.

**Two issues**

1. the soft-keyboard shall not be
   dismiss-able for this activity
2. the soft-keyboard needs to be
   elevated 50 pixels from the bottom
   of the screen

Looking for assistance to solve these two issues. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**to solve #1**

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard()
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mAutoCompleteTextView.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}

private void showSoftKeyboard()
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```

**#2 has no solution**